# Phony-Targets for ansible skips $

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, makefile

I'm new to Makefile. Here is my PHONY target for ansible in Makefile

```
.PHONY: healthcheck-webproxy
healthcheck-webproxy:
    ansible-playbook -i inventory.py  -e "env=dev" -e "group=webproxy" -e "command='curl -k 
    -s https://localhost:${nginx_https_port}/healthcheck'" site.yaml  -- 
    limit=vm4node.lite.com  -bv
```

When i run `make healthcheck-webproxy` it skips ${nginx_https_port}
i get the below ansible adhoc

```
$make healthcheck-webproxy
ansible-playbook -i inventory.py  -e "env=dev" -e "group=webproxy" -e "command='curl -k -s https://localhost:/healthcheck'" limit=vm4node.lite.com  -bv
```

could someone please help me with this. I don't want makefile to skip ${nginx_https_port}
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I would like to add the code here.

```
- hosts: "{{ env }}"
  gather_facts: false
  become: true
  become_method: sudo
  tasks:
  - name: Check HealthService
    shell: docker exec {{ container_name }} sh -c {{ command | quote }}
```

At the Shell it should execute this way.

#docker exec webproxy  sh -c 'curl -k -s https://localhost:${nginx_https_port}/healthcheck'

Comment: Is `nginx_https_port` by any chance supposed to be an *environment* variable?  The rule as written will attempt to interpret it as a *`make`* variable.  You can fix that by doubling the `$` to escape it to `make`.  Alternatively, you can specify a value for it (as a `make` variable) either in the makefile or on the `make` command line.

Comment: @JohnBollinger If it were an environment variable it would have been imported into GNU make as a make variable, so this would work.

Comment: Make is not "skipping" that variable: it's expanding that variable and that variable has no value, so it is expanded to the empty string as you see.  You need to set that variable to something.  Where is it supposed to be set?  Is there somewhere else in your makefile that is supposed to set it?  Is it supposed to be set on the command line (`make nginx_https_port=8888`)?  You'll have to provide more info before we can help because the above part of a makefile doesn't tell us.

Comment: yes, it is env variable.

Comment: yes, it is env variable. I dont define the variable.. it should take it from the specified container. i tried with https://localhost:$${nginx_https_port}/healthcheck  and https://localhost:$(${nginx_https_port})/ both of them don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the `$` in the makefile. Turn `${nginx_https_port}` into `\${nginx_https_port}`.

The string in your makefile is:

`"command='curl -k -s https://localhost:${nginx_https_port}/healthcheck'"`

Since it's a string encased by double quotes, variable substitution/expansion happens. So `${nginx_https_port}` is expanded in the makefile, on the host the makefile runs on. To prevent that, you need the escape the $, so the string is loaded into ansible as-is.

In single quote strings (e.g. 'echo $hello') no variable substitution/expansion happens, which is also why the docker exec (executed on the shell) works for you:

`docker exec webproxy sh -c 'curl -k -s https://localhost:${nginx_https_port}/healthcheck'`

Here the string `curl -k -s https://localhost:${nginx_https_port}/healthcheck'` is given as-is to the sh inside the docker container, where then it is executed without any quotes and the variable can be expanded.